# How to get maps rendered inside of a CardView

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm wondering how to get the map to appear inside the CardView, like in the images below, highlighted in pink.

On the left is Strava, it shows the map with the route highilghted. On the right is Google Calendar, it has a map of the location of the calender event.

[image: strava on the left, google calendar on the right]

I would really appriciate some pointer on where to look in the apis to achieve this.

Regards,
Luke

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a MapView to achieve this.

This is part of Androids [Lite Mode](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/lite).

Create your card, and add the `MapView` inside the `CardView`.

Then in your `onCreate()`, you create the actual map and set the `MapView` to display that map.

Comment: Thank you TejjD. This is what I was looking for.